# libcocos2d libraries.a & PROJNAME.app missing

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode3.2

I have this new project created via the cocos2d 1.0.1 template in Xcode and I was copying over files from the project whose cocos2d engine is outdated (it's dated to 99.4, but it didn't have a CCSpriteBatchNode, instead using CCSpriteSheet) and I was rearrange files around into folders that matched the setup of the old file.

One of the folders is Products, which I stuck in the 'Code' folder. However, the two files within this Products folder have gone red:

```
MyGame.app
libcocos2d libraries.a
```

meaning they're undefined, and I need help solving this conundrum, I'm very new to paths and directories. Here's a screenshot:

http://i207.photobucket.com/albums/bb289/teh_Mac/Screenshot2011-12-21at90907PM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you created the new project, you should only add source code files and resource files to your project. There's no need to recreate the Products folder.

Besides, the .app and .a are files that are created during the build process. Until you've made a successful build, they will remain in red. And even if the build was successful they may remain red due to bugs in Xcode.